# Spring boot with react and JWT: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, cors

I have this on spring boot:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addIntHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 10);

    final String token = getTokenFromRequest(request);
    final String username;

    if (token==null)
    {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    username=jwtService.getUsernameFromToken(token);

    if (username!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null)
    {
        UserDetails userDetails=userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails))
        {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken= new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
        }


        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public class DemoController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE},allowedHeaders = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo() {
        DemoResponse demoResponse = new DemoResponse("JWT passed");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(demoResponse);
    }
```

And this is my react code

```
const Demo = ({ token }) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/demo', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

And this is the error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/demo' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This part is basically what I added, trying to fix the problem

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
```